# Longitude and latitude do not show correctly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude

I am now trying to plot the map of Canada in `ggplot2` and I find that the longitude and latitude are not correctly showed in the map. Is there any solution? Thanks a lot.

The arcgis shapfile is downloaded from https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dcbcdf86939548af81efbd2d732336db

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
countries<-readOGR("Canada.shp", layer="Canada")
ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=countries,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill='white',color = "black")
```

[image]

The longitude in the map should be like 110W, 100W, 90W. And the latitude in the map should be like 50N, 60N, 70N. However, it is not the case for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coordinates are not lat-long:

```
> summary(countries)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
         min     max
x -2314694.5 3093025
y   321591.9 4811137
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
+datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0]
```

they are "aea", which is Albers Equal Area with the given parameters.

To convert to lat-long, use `spTransform` with projection "epsg:4326" to convert to WGS84 lat-long, as used in GPS systems.

```
> ca = spTransform(countries, "+init=epsg:4326")
> summary(ca)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
         min       max
x -141.00301 -52.62028
y   41.91332  83.10832
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am not familiar with the map drawing and I wonder if I can use the `datum=NAD83` while keeping the projection method as `epsg:4326`. Because `datum=NAD83` is a better datum for Canada. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A datum isn't a projection, and the NAD83 and WGS84 datum only differ by a few metres across Canada. Why not leave them in the original projection, that seems to have been set up for Canada. If you want to draw lines of lat and long you can do it, but they'll be curves.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: Hello, sorry to trouble you again. I wonder how I can draw lines of latitude and longitude (curves are OK) on this map. Thanks a lot.